# How to migrate from custom Membership Provider to SqlMembershipProvider?

Tags: asp.net, membership, sqlmembershipprovider

I'm currently using a very basic custom implementation of [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) in an ASP.NET web application. As my requirements for membership increase, it seems to make a lot of sense to use an existing, full featured, and well tested implementation like [SqlMembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.aspx). I've figured out how to use the aspnet_Memebership stored procedures to create users from my custom tables, but I'm stuck on the password. My custom implementation doesn't use salt, and SqlMembershipProvider seems to require it.

I want this to be a smooth transition for my users and not require everyone to update their password the first time they login after the change.

**How do I migrate hashed passwords from a custom implementation (see below) to SqlMemberhipProvider?**

```
FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, FormsAuthPasswordFormat.SHA1.ToString())
```

**Update**: I should clarify that my custom provider is an implementation of MembershipProvider, just not a full featured one. Also, I've tried using aspnet`_Membership`_CreateUser with empty salt, but the hashes don't match.

Comment: Personally, I find the standard Membership provider a pain in the butt, and basically completely unusable.. YMMV :P

Comment: @Thorarin - What don't you like about SqlMembershipProvider?

Comment: I gave up after a few days of trying to migrate my users. I'm just going to add the missing features to my custom provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom hash algorithm that removes the salt (the first 16 bytes of the combined salt-and-password).

http://forums.asp.net/t/981295.aspx

Alternatively you could probably write your own class that inherits MembershipProvider, but this would be more work.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to try to create the `SqlMembership`'s users manually (through the stored procedures) with an *empty* salt.

If that doesn't work, I think you're out of luck with the `SqlMembershipProvider`, but you could always write your own `MembershipProvider` (possibly even based on the `SqlMembershipProvider`'s own back-end). It's not that hard.

Comment: @Ruben - You and Axl both deserve to get answer credit, but Axl needs the rep more :)

Answer (score 0):

Override the  System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
 class, and override as many or as few methods as you need to customize.

web.config not seen here.  but the fact that you got your own custom one working in the first place, I don't that part is a tripping point.

```
public class SqlMembershipProviderOverride : System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider
{
    public static readonly string FORCED_OVERRIDE_APPLICATION_NAME = "MyApplicationName";

    public SqlMembershipProviderOverride()
    {
        this.ApplicationName = FORCED_OVERRIDE_APPLICATION_NAME;
    }

    public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        return base.CreateUser(username, password, email, passwordQuestion, passwordAnswer,    isApproved, providerUserKey, out status);
        /*
              Do "your own thing" in this or any other override method
        */

    }


}
```